# Send JMS message from mainframe

Tags: jms, cobol, mainframe

I was wondering if it's possible to send a JMS message from a mainframe application running COBOL and/or JCL. I see there are adapters for .Net and other technologies such as JNBridge http://www.jnbridge.com/, but is there anything to allow mainframe applications to send messages?

Comment: Yes. Have you googled? Where do you want to send it from? A CICS application? IMS? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is easily doable.  It depends upon your JMS provider.  If you use WebsphereMQ, there are direct called modules to send messages -- CSQCPUT and CSQCPUT1, IIRC.

Your provider should have something documented about how to send a message.